# Supervisor: process already running при настройке Supervisor через Ansible

Tags: ansible, supervisord

Настраиваю Supervisord в Ansible.

`notify` делаю для рестарта.

Хэндлер, который в итоге должен рестартнуть supervisord:

```
- name: restart supervisord
  sudo: yes
  service: name=supervisord state=restarted
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
msg: Stopping Supervisor: supervisord.
Starting Supervisor: process already running.
```

С чего вдруг такая ошибка возникает?

С другими сервисами такой проблемы не возникало.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Не зависит от очереди.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Единственное, к чему подтолкнула [документация](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/service_module.html), так это поставить `sleep`:

```
- name: restart supervisord
  sudo: yes
  service: name=supervisord state=restarted sleep=5
```

Теперь ошибки нет. Вероятно, без `sleep` Ansible пытался запустить supervisord раньше, чем успевал его остановить.

Comment: Перечитал доки. Похоже, все правильно, это типичный workaround для такой ситуации.

Comment: кстати, у нас вчера два вопроса по [tag:ansible] за день. Рекорд )

Comment: @NickVolynkin растём )